# PHP Password checker

Tags: php, passwords

I have written a password checker using PHP and It worked fine. It consists of many "if else". Is there any way to minimize my usage of "if else" in my code?

```
function passtest($pass) {
            if (!empty($pass)) { //check if string is empty
                if (ctype_alnum($pass)) { //check if string is alphanumeric
                    if (7 < strlen($pass)){ //check if string meets 8 or more characters
                        if (strcspn($pass, '0123456789') != strlen($pass)){ //check if string has numbers
                            if (strcspn($pass, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') != strlen($pass)) { //check if string has small letters
                                if (strcspn($pass, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') != strlen($pass)) { //check if string has capital letters
                                    return "<br />Password passed";
                                }
                                else {
                                    return "<br />No capital letter";
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                return "<br />No small letter";
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            return "<br />No number";
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return "<br />Password is short";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return "<br />Password has special character";
                }
            }
            else {
                return "<br />Password field is empty";
            }
        }
```

Comment: This probably belongs on the Code Review site. But the first thing I'd say is from a UI perspective, collate **all** the reasons a password fails in one go, so the user doesn't have to make 3 or 4 attempts at getting a "good" password.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: Moving out to Code Review

Comment: i refuse to use sites that make me use what the site wrongly thinks is a good password

Comment: This isn't at a "review" stage. We should vote to close to avoid spamming our other "departments" (imo).  @user3326060, there are various ways to improve this. Firstly, each check you  want to perform would likely be better an `elseif` (or switch). Also, look at stripping out your `echo` altogether and return a value (perhaps, depends on the state of the rest of your code)

Comment: As Lego says, run all the tests even if one fails. You may be able to use a list of regexs instead, making the code even more succinct. I agree this would be better on _Code Review_, but +1 for wanting to improve your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: xkcd]
> [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/936/)

Your function should just test to see if a password was entered. Other than that, *it is not your place to tell people what they can and can't use for a password*. How long would it take for a hacker to realise my password is Pokémon, for example? That special character is a HUGE entropy booster.

That aside, to actually answer your question, try formulating your statements in the negative:

```
if( empty($pass)) return "<br />Password field is empty";
if( !ctype_alnum($pass)) return "<br />Password has special character":
// ...
```

This has the handy side-effect of keeping the error messages next to the condition they represent.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `if elseif else` statement.

```
function passtest($pass) {   
  if (empty($pass)){ //check if string is empty
    return "<br />Password field is empty";
  }elseif (!ctype_alnum($pass)){ //check if string is alphanumeric
    return "<br />Password has special character";
  }elseif (strlen($pass) < 8) { //check if string meets 8 or more characters
    return "<br />Password is short";
  }elseif (strspn($pass, '0123456789') != strlen($pass)){ //check if string has numbers
    return "<br />No number";
  }elseif (strspn($pass, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') != strlen($pass)) { //check if string has small letters
    return "<br />No small letter";
  }elseif (strspn($pass, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') != strlen($pass)) { //check if string has capital letters
    return "<br />No capital letter";
  }else{
    return "<br />Password passed";
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be best if you could elaborate on your answer a bit.

Comment: @dcc Done. Note that I have replaced `strcspn()` with `strspn()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your concerned with using if else statements and not concerned with readability you could avoid them all together..

```
function passtest($pass) {
    return !empty($pass) ? ctype_alnum($pass) ? 7 < strlen($pass) ? strcspn($pass, '0123456789') != strlen($pass) ? strcspn($pass, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') != strlen($pass) ? strcspn($pass, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') != strlen($pass) ? "<br />Password passed" : "<br />No capital letter" : "<br />No small letter" : "<br />No number" : "<br />Password is short" : "<br />Password has special character" : "<br />Password field is empty";
}
```